# How to parse complicated XML

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I have this structure XML. And I am trying to parse it to an array but I am having a problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <CheckDealNoStatusResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <CheckDealNoStatusResult>
            <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
                <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="tbl" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:element name="tbl">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="Temp1" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0" />
                                        <xs:element name="Temp2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                        <xs:element name="Temp3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:choice>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:schema>
            <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
                <NewDataSet xmlns="">
                    <tbl diffgr:id="tbl1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                        <Temp1>12929011</Temp1>
                        <Temp2>Pending</Temp2>
                        <Temp3>Pending</Temp3>
                    </tbl>
                </NewDataSet>
            </diffgr:diffgram>
        </CheckDealNoStatusResult>
        <ErrorMsg />
    </CheckDealNoStatusResponse>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Im trying to parse it this way

```
$parser = simplexml_load_string($smlString, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);

  echo "<br /><br /><br /><pre>";
        print_r( $parser );
        echo "</pre>";
```

But Im only getting this.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [CheckDealNoStatusResponse] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [CheckDealNoStatusResult] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [ErrorMsg] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

        )

)
```

How can get these information

```
 <Temp1>12929011</Temp1>
 <Temp2>Pending</Temp2>
 <Temp3>Pending</Temp3>
```

Comment: Looks like it got parsed. What are you asking?

Comment: @pvg, Im hoping to get this infirmation  <Temp1>292901</Temp1>
                        <Temp2>Pending</Temp2>
                        <Temp3>Pending</Temp3>

Comment: This is not just XML, it is SOAP. PHP has a specific extension for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution might be to use [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) and register the namespaces with [registerXPathNamespace](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php).
You can then use the [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) method to find your elements.

For example:

```
$smlString = <<<SOURCE
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <CheckDealNoStatusResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <CheckDealNoStatusResult>
            <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
                <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="tbl" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:element name="tbl">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="Temp1" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0" />
                                        <xs:element name="Temp2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                        <xs:element name="Temp3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:choice>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:schema>
            <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
                <NewDataSet xmlns="">
                    <tbl diffgr:id="tbl1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                        <Temp1>12929011</Temp1>
                        <Temp2>Pending</Temp2>
                        <Temp3>Pending</Temp3>
                    </tbl>
                </NewDataSet>
            </diffgr:diffgram>
        </CheckDealNoStatusResult>
        <ErrorMsg />
    </CheckDealNoStatusResponse>
</soap:Envelope>
SOURCE;

$parser = simplexml_load_string($smlString, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$ns = $parser->getNamespaces(true);
$parser->registerXPathNamespace('tempuri', $ns['']);
$parser->registerXPathNamespace('diffgr', $ns['diffgr']);

$elements = $parser->xpath('//tempuri:CheckDealNoStatusResponse/tempuri:CheckDealNoStatusResult/diffgr:diffgram/NewDataSet/tbl');
$element = $elements[0];

var_dump($element->Temp1->__toString());
var_dump($element->Temp2->__toString());
var_dump($element->Temp3->__toString());
```

Will result in:

```
string(8) "12929011"
string(7) "Pending"
string(7) "Pending"
```

The `$element` variable is of type [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php). You can for example access the 'Temp1', 'Temp2' or 'Temp3' properties which are also of type SimpleXMLElement and use their [__toString()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php) method to get the text content.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/5NA2h)